# PyCaret installation

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, pycaret

I encountered an error while installing the PyCaret package .

```
ERROR: numba 0.54.1 has requirement numpy<1.21,>=1.17, but you'll have numpy 1.22.4 which is incompatible.
ERROR: imageio 2.21.1 has requirement pillow>=8.3.2, but you'll have pillow 7.0.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: shap 0.41.0 has requirement packaging>20.9, but you'll have packaging 20.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: flask-simplelogin 0.1.1 has requirement click<9.0.0,>=8.0.1, but you'll have click 7.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: explainerdashboard 0.4.0 has requirement scikit-learn>=1.1, but you'll have scikit-learn 0.23.2 which is incompatible.
ERROR: bokeh 2.4.3 has requirement pillow>=7.1.0, but you'll have pillow 7.0.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: holoviews 1.15.0 has requirement panel>=0.13.1, but you'll have panel 0.12.7 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorboardx 2.5.1 has requirement protobuf<=3.20.1,>=3.8.0, but you'll have protobuf 4.21.5 which is incompatible.
ERROR: ray 1.13.0 has requirement protobuf<4.0.0,>=3.15.3, but you'll have protobuf 4.21.5 which is incompatible.
ERROR: evidently 0.1.56.dev0 has requirement scikit-learn>=0.24.0, but you'll have scikit-learn 0.23.2 which is incompatible.
```

When I was trying to run an example to train a data set , the code

```
# compare all models
best = compare_models()
```

returned nothing including any error.
Kindly advise as to how this version anomaly can be corrected.

Comment: I think you are using outdated version of packages check `pip list --outdated`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing something wrong. Installation of PyCaret is generally straightforward. Simply:

```
pip install pycaret
```

And if you are using Google Colab IDE:

```
!pip install pycaret
```

Other than this, the error can be related to scikit-learn, notice the error in your post:

```
ERROR: explainerdashboard 0.4.0 has requirement scikit-learn>=1.1, but you'll have scikit-learn 0.23.2 which is incompatible.
```

Here is some info from this link: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html

> **Warning:** Scikit-learn 0.20 was the last version to support Python 2.7 and Python 3.4. Scikit-learn 0.21 supported Python 3.5-3.7. Scikit-learn 0.22 supported Python 3.5-3.8. Scikit-learn 0.23 - 0.24 require Python 3.6 or newer. Scikit-learn 1.0 supported Python 3.7-3.10. Scikit-learn 1.1 and later requires Python 3.8 or newer.

You can use this code:

```
pip install scikit-learn==1.1.3
```

And for Google Colab IDE:

```
!pip install scikit-learn==1.1.3
```

When using pip install, use scikit-learn, not sklearn.

You had better follow one of the tutorials below which you can find here:

https://pycaret.gitbook.io/docs/get-started/tutorials

[Binary Classification](https://nbviewer.org/github/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/tutorials/Binary%20Classification%20Tutorial%20Level%20Beginner%20-%20%20CLF101.ipynb)
[Multiclass Classification](https://nbviewer.org/github/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/tutorials/Multiclass%20Classification%20Tutorial%20Level%20Beginner%20-%20MCLF101.ipynb)

[Regression](https://nbviewer.org/github/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/tutorials/Regression%20Tutorial%20Level%20Beginner%20-%20REG101.ipynb)
[Clustering](https://nbviewer.org/github/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/tutorials/Clustering%20Tutorial%20Level%20Beginner%20-%20CLU101.ipynb)

[Anomaly Detection](https://nbviewer.org/github/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/tutorials/Anomaly%20Detection%20Tutorial%20Level%20Beginner%20-%20ANO101.ipynb)
[Natural Language Processing](https://nbviewer.org/github/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/tutorials/Natural%20Language%20Processing%20Tutorial%20Level%20Beginner%20-%20NLP101.ipynb)

[Association Rules](https://nbviewer.org/github/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/tutorials/Association%20Rule%20Mining%20Tutorial%20-%20ARUL01.ipynb)
[Time Series Forecasting](https://nbviewer.org/github/pycaret/pycaret/tree/master/examples/time_series/forecasting/)

You can also use Google Colab IDE, in your chrome browser, by entering
https://colab.research.google.com/